# noob javascript recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm a sys admin trying to learn javascript as a first language. One of the text I am studying has this code example in the chapter on recursion.

(variables changed for simplicity)

```
function fruit(n) {
    return n > 1 ? fruit(n - 1) + "apples" : "bananas";
}
```

I understand the ternary operator aspect of the function, the same thing could be written as this:

```
function fruit(n) {
    if n > 1
      return fruit(n - 1) + "apples";
    else
      return "bananas";
}
```

when I call the function I get the following result

```
console.log(fruit(3));

bananas apples apples
```

I don't understand how the first value is bananas (would that not mean the conditional 3 > 1 would be false)? What is going on in terms of how this code is executed to come up with that result?

Not sure if this site is noob friendly but thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The first conditional calls fruit again. Run through the code on paper.

Answer (score 4):

When figuring out recursion, it's best to start with the base case. In this case, your base case is `fruit(1)` - I hope it's clear that this returns `bananas`.

Now consider `fruit(2)` - this will return `fruit(1) + "apples"`, and we already know `fruit(1)` is `bananas`, so this means `bananas apples`.

Extend this case further - `fruit(3)` is basically `fruit(2) + "apples"`, and you already know what `fruit(2)` is... you end up with `"bananas apples" + "apples"`, giving you your result.

Comment: that is a great way to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code like follows:

```
<script>
function fruit(n) {
    console.log("Called with " + n);
    if (n > 1) {
      return fruit(n - 1) + "apples ";
    } else {
      console.log("Called with " + n + " returning bananas.");
      return "bananas ";
    }
}
console.log(fruit(3));
</script>
```

My output:

```
Called with 3
Called with 2
Called with 1
Called with 1 returning bananas.
bananas apples apples
```

The line return fruit(n - 1) + "apples "; means you concatenate a string: "bananas" + "apple" + "apple".

Looking on every step:

```
fruit(3):
- calling fruit(2)
- - calling fruit(1)
- - get return "bananas" // string consinst of "bananas" only here
- get return "apple" // string = "bananas" + "apple"
get return "apple" // string = "bananas" + "apple" + "apple"
```

EDIT:
If you want to have bananas at the end.
Change

```
return fruit(n - 1) + "apples ";
```

to

```
return "apples " + fruit(n - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because recursion continues as follows:

```
function fruit(n) {
if n > 1
  return fruit(n - 1) + "apples";
else
  return "bananas";
}
```

In the example you gave (listed above) you check to see if `n > 1`. In this case `n = 3` so the answer is yes. So what do we do? We execute fruit(2).

Is 2 greater than 1? yes, so what do we do? We execute fruit(1).

Is 1 > 1? No, so we write Bananas.

Then recursion sort of back-tracks, writing the apples and apples as it returns to finish the previous methods.

VISUAL EXAMPLE:
Since we know that the function will return "bananas" only when `n <= 1`

`function fruit(3)` will return SOMETHING and then write "apples"

```
  fruit(3) = fruit(2) apples
  fruit(2) = fruit(1) apples
  fruit(1) = banana
```

so you see, therefore substituting `[fruit(2)]` and `(fruit(1))`:

```
fruit(3) = [fruit(1) apples] apples
fruit(3) = [(banana) apples] apples
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trace your code, it will be clearer what is going on.

You can think of recursion as layers, and each call goes deeper and deeper in. When these calls resolve, they resolve in the reverse order, with the latest recursion resolving first, then coming outwards to the outward layer.

If you wanted to print the latest recursion at the end you should change

```
return fruit(n-1) + "apples"
```

to

```
return "apples"+ fruit(n-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a binary tree structure in a paper you will start to understand,
Firstly 3 is given which will be true so it will return
fruit(2)+"apple"
continue this until you reach the else part and then start to go up in the binary tree and you will get the output,
always try to think how a computer would process it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).